# How to process an x-column text file to get a y-column one?

Tags: text-formatting

I have a text file:

```
a   aa  aaa     b   bb  bbb     c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd     e   ee  eee     f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg     h   hh  hhh     i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

How can I process it and get a 2 column file like this:

```
a   aa
aaa b
bb  bbb
c   cc
ccc d
dd  ddd
e   ee
eee f
ff  fff
g   gg
ggg h
hh  hhh
i   ii
iii j
jj  jjj
```

Or a three column file like this:

```
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd
e   ee  eee
f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg
h   hh  hhh
i   ii  iii
j   jj  jj
```

I prefer to get awk solution but other solutions are welcomed too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put each field on a line and post-columnate.

## Each field on one line

#### tr

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < infile
```

#### grep

```
grep -o '[[:alnum:]]*' infile
```

#### sed

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' infile
```

or more portable:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\
/g' infile
```

#### awk

```
awk '$1=$1' OFS='\n' infile
```

or

```
awk -v OFS='\n' '$1=$1' infile
```

## Columnate

#### paste

For 2 columns:

```
... | paste - -
```

For 3 columns:

```
... | paste - - -
```

etc.

#### sed

For 2 columns:

```
... | sed 'N; s/\n/\t/g'
```

For 3 columns:

```
... | sed 'N; N; s/\n/\t/g'
```

etc.

#### xargs

```
... | xargs -n number-of-desired-columns
```

As `xargs` uses `/bin/echo` to print, beware that data that looks like options to `echo` will be interpreted as such.

#### awk

```
... | awk '{ printf "%s", $0 (NR%n==0?ORS:OFS) }' n=number-of-desired-columns OFS='\t'
```

#### pr

```
... | pr -at -number-of-desired-columns
```

or

```
... | pr -at -s$'\t' -number-of-desired-columns
```

#### columns (from the autogen package)

```
... | columns -c number-of-desired-columns
```

## Typical output:

```
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd
e   ee  eee
f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg
h   hh  hhh
i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

Comment: Slam dunk. +1 sir

Comment: Shouldn't the `xargs` line call `echo` or `printf`?

Comment: @Wildcard: `xargs` calls `/bin/echo` by default

Comment: Wow, I had no idea!  It's even [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html#tag_20_158_05).  Thanks!

Comment: @Wildcard: Sending data to `xargs` that looks like options to `/bin/echo` causes problems ... I added a warning.

Answer (score 9):

As Wildcard pointed out, this will only work if your file is nicely formatted, in that there aren't any special characters that the shell will interpret as globs and you are happy with the default word splitting rules.  If there's any question about whether your files will "pass" that test, do not use this approach.

One possibility would be to use `printf` to do it like

```
printf '%s\t%s\n' $(cat your_file)
```

That will do word splitting on the contents of `your_file` and will pair them and print them with tabs in between.  You could use more `%s` format strings in the `printf` to have extra columns.

Comment: The depends on the file containing no special characters.  If it has, for instance, any asterisks (\*) you will get very unexpected results.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ sed -E 's/\s+/\n/g' ip.txt | paste - -
a   aa
aaa b
bb  bbb
c   cc
ccc d
dd  ddd
e   ee
eee f
ff  fff
g   gg
ggg h
hh  hhh
i   ii
iii j
jj  jjj

$ sed -E 's/\s+/\n/g' ip.txt | paste - - -
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd
e   ee  eee
f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg
h   hh  hhh
i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -n0E 'say s/\s+/ ++$n % 4 ?"\t":"\n"/gre' file
```

(replace 4 by the number of columns)

Answer (score 4):

BSD `rs` (reshape) utility:

```
$ rs 0 2
a   aa  aaa     b   bb  bbb     c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd     e   ee  eee     f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg     h   hh  hhh     i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
a    aa
aaa  b
bb   bbb
c    cc
ccc  d
dd   ddd
e    ee
eee  f
ff   fff
g    gg
ggg  h
hh   hhh
i    ii
iii  j
jj   jjj
```

`0 2` is *rows* and *columns*. Specifying `0` means "calculate rows automatically from columns".

Answer (score 3):

#### Python script approach.

Basic idea here is to flatten all the words in your text into one list, and then print new-line after each second item (that's for columnating in to two columns). If you want 3 columns , change `index%2` to `index%3`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

items = [i for l in sys.stdin 
           for i in l.strip().split()]
line = []
for index,item in enumerate(items,1):
    line.append(item)
    if index%2 == 0:
       print("\t".join(line))
       line = []
```

Sample output:

```
$ python recolumnate.py < input.txt                                            
a   aa
aaa b
bb  bbb
c   cc
ccc d
dd  ddd
e   ee
eee f
ff  fff
g   gg
ggg h
hh  hhh
i   ii
iii j
jj  jjj
```

---

Three-column version (as said above, only `index%3 == 0` changed)

```
$ cat recolumnate.py                                                           
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

items = [i for l in sys.stdin 
           for i in l.strip().split()]
line = []
for index,item in enumerate(items,1):
    line.append(item)
    if index%3 == 0:
       print("\t".join(line))
       line = []

$ python recolumnate.py < input.txt                                            
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd
e   ee  eee
f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg
h   hh  hhh
i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a single invocation of GNU awk:

**reshape.awk**

```awk
# Set awk to split input at whitespace characters and
# use tab as the output field separator 
BEGIN {
  RS="[ \t\n]+"
  OFS="\t"
}

# Print using OFS or ORS based on the element index
{
  printf "%s", $1 (NR%n == 0 ? ORS : OFS)
}

# Append a missing new-line when last row is not full
END { 
  if( NR%n != 0) 
    printf "\n"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f reshape.awk n=2 infile
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk -v n=2 'BEGIN { RS="[ \t\n]+"; OFS="\t" } { printf "%s", $1 (NR%n == 0 ? ORS : OFS) } END { if( NR%n != 0) printf "\n" }' infile
```

Output:

```
a   aa
aaa b
bb  bbb
c   cc
ccc d
dd  ddd
e   ee
eee f
ff  fff
g   gg
ggg h
hh  hhh
i   ii
iii j
jj  jjj
```

Or with `n=3`:

```
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd
e   ee  eee
f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg
h   hh  hhh
i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

Comment: Doesn't this use `$1` as the *format* string to `printf`?

Comment: @Wildcard: Right, it is safer to use `"%s", ...`. Updated

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  :)  The same applies to the `awk` command in your other answer to this question, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Two columns

```
perl -pne "s/ /\n/g" filename| sed '/^$/d'| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
a aa
aaa b
bb bbb
c cc
ccc d
dd ddd
e ee
eee f
ff fff
g gg
ggg h
hh hhh
i ii
iii j
jj jjj
```

Three columns

```
    perl -pne "s/ /\n/g" filename| sed '/^$/d'| sed "1~3N;s/\n/ /g"| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"

a aa aaa
b bb bbb
c cc ccc
d dd ddd
e ee eee
f ff fff
g gg ggg
h hh hhh
i ii iii
j jj jjj
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Converting to 2-column output:*

```
~$ raku -e '.put for words.batch(2);'   file
```

*Converting to 3-column output:*

```
~$ raku -e '.put for words.batch(3);'   file
```

Raku has a `words` function that splits on whitespace. Once split the elements can be `batch`ed back together. You use `batch` in Raku if you anticipate an incomplete/partial set of elements at the end (equivalent to `rotor(partial => True)` ). If you have the need to drop the final incomplete/partial set of elements at the end, use `rotor()` with defaults.

Sample Input:

```
a   aa  aaa     b   bb  bbb     c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd     e   ee  eee     f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg     h   hh  hhh     i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

Sample Output (2-column joined on `\t`):

```
~$ raku -e '.join("\t").put for words.batch(2);'  file
a   aa
aaa b
bb  bbb
c   cc
ccc d
dd  ddd
e   ee
eee f
ff  fff
g   gg
ggg h
hh  hhh
i   ii
iii j
jj  jjj
```

Sample Output (3-column joined on `\t`):

```
~$ raku -e '.join("\t").put for words.batch(3);'  file
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
d   dd  ddd
e   ee  eee
f   ff  fff
g   gg  ggg
h   hh  hhh
i   ii  iii
j   jj  jjj
```

Finally, if your initial elements are not whitespace-separated, you can `slurp` the file in all at once and for example `split(/ \, | \n)` split on commas and newlines. See the first link below for an example.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686651/227738
https://raku.org