# Display output in column form

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have written a shell script that displays username, terminal name, login time etc using `case`. The code is:

```
echo "Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time"
read ch
case $ch in
1)
echo `who | cut -c1-8 | cut -d" " -f1`
;;
2)
echo `who | cut -c9-16 | column`
;;
3)
echo `who | cut -c22-32 | sort`
;;
4)
echo `who | cut -c34-39`
;;
esac
```

When I run this script the output comes in a single line and I want it to be displayed in a columnar format (i.e. listed across multiple lines in a single column). I have tried the `cut`, `column` and `sort` commands, and yet no respite. The output is:

```
Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time
1
bioinfo class class class class class class class class class class
[class@bio ~]$
```

Comment: see if this helps: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308631/how-to-process-a-multi-column-text-file-to-get-another-multi-column-text-file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is `class` and why is it repeated so many times? How did you run the script? Which option did you choose to get this output? Why are you using `echo` for commands that print their output to stdout anyway?

Comment: It is pretty clear that class is the username, result obtained after using the who command.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk` instead of `cut` for this, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time"
read ch
case $ch in
    1)  
    who | awk '{ print $1 }'
    ;;  
    2)  
    who | awk '{ print $2 }'
    ;;  
    3)  
    who | awk '{ print $3 " " $4 }'
    ;;  
    4)  
    who | awk '{ print $5 }'
    ;;  
    *)  
    echo "Wrong input"
esac
```

Execution samples:

```
./whoList.sh 
Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time
2
console
ttys000
ttys001

./whoList.sh 
Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time
3
Oct 3
Oct 3
Oct 3

./whoList.sh 
Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time
1
maulinglawns
maulinglawns
maulinglawns

./whoList.sh 
Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time
4
09:01
09:44
11:01

./whoList.sh
Press 1 for user name, 2 for terminal name, 3 for login date and 4 for time
7
Wrong input
```

The output, as you can see, is all in one **column**, not on a single line.

Edit: 
Tested under OS X 10.11.6

`bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`