# How every group of N consecutive rows are folded into one, and separated by tab?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I am trying to solve one competitive question, where I'm stuck at below scenario can some one help me out to understand how the output can be achieved

**Explanation :** Every group of three consecutive rows should be folded into one

[ *Output is shared below* ]

**Data in file :**

```
Abc 123,
zyxhj pqr
raj
ram:
vilas, 
1234
jkal
yui
gshj
```

**Output :**

```
Abc 123,zyxhj pqr raj
ram:vilas,1234
jkal yui gshj
```

Comment: Please search around or show your efforts when trying to solve your problem. In the output, some lines are joined with spaces, some others are not. Why?

Comment: [How to process a multi column text file to get another multi column text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308631/how-to-process-a-multi-column-text-file-to-get-another-multi-column-text-file) not exact duplicate, but portion of the answers can be used here:

Comment: The last group may be incomplete -- one or two lines? I would expect xargs and paste to correctly terminate the short output line, and awk to leave it without a newline (it would need an END block for that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xargs`:

```
xargs -d'\n' -n3 <infile
```

read and print every 3 lines according to the `\n`ewline as delimiter

---

Using `paste`:

```
paste -d ' ' - - - <infile
```

paste data in 3 columns with space delimiter

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%3?OFS:ORS) }' infile
```

printf every line and then print OFS (Output Field Separator; space by default) if NR (Number of Record) was not module of 3 else ORS (Output Record Separator; newline by default) if it was.

Comment: Oh indeed, last 3 lines don't match the behaviour of previous

Comment: @αғsнιη I used `paste -d - - -`  this as work for me

Comment: Also, as you already do the good conditional, you could do this alternative: `awk '{ORS = (NR%3 ? OFS : "\n") }1' file` (which allows someone to forget `printf` secret issues temporarily)

Comment: @thanasisp [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617431/how-every-group-of-n-consecutive-rows-are-folded-into-one-and-separated-by-tab/617435?noredirect=1#comment1155031_617435)'s also nice!